# How do you use the and operator in python?

Tags: python

I have 4 variables labeled a, b, c, and d. I wanted to compare them to each other using if statements and the and operator.

Would I use the and operator like this...

```
if a == b and c:
```

Or like this...

```
if a == b and c == d:
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compare them to each other"?

Comment: Neither. You'd use `==`

Comment: use lower case - `if (a==b) and (c==d):`

Comment: There is no `AND` operator, but this is an `and` operator. What part of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) —which says "The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned." — is unclear?

Comment: `=` is for assigning a value to a variable.  `==` is for comparing things.  `and` (lower case) is used to "combine" clauses.

Comment: What _are_ `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`?  What value(s) are they and what are you comparing them to?  `if a == b and c:` is valid syntax, but it may not be the logic you are looking for.  `if a == b and c == d:` is also valid syntax, but its logic is different .  What are you trying to do?  What are the variables' values and what result are you looking for?

Comment: The code you write depends on the comparisons you want to make and the logic they need to have. "Compare them to each other" is too vague.

Answer (score 2):

the `and` operator is used to check if multiple statements are true or false try this:

```
if a == b and c == d:
    print('hello world')
```

Comment: `and` needs to be lower case.

Comment: @RocketHazmat my bad